# Lottie animation's load() method is not a function error on jest tests (Angular)

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest, lottie

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */
import {
  AfterViewInit, Component, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';

interface HTMLLottiePlayerElement extends HTMLElement {
  load(animationData: any): void;
  play(): void;
  stop(): void;
  setLooping(isLooping: boolean): void;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'rt-marker',
  templateUrl: './rt-marker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rt-marker.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class RtMarkerComponent implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit {
  marker: HTMLLottiePlayerElement | null = null;
  circle: HTMLLottiePlayerElement | null = null;

  @Input() animate = false;
  @Input() circleAnimate = false;
  @ViewChild('markerRef', { static: true }) markerRef: ElementRef | null = null;
  @ViewChild('circleRef', { static: true }) circleRef: ElementRef | null = null;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.marker = this.markerRef?.nativeElement;
    this.circle = this.circleRef?.nativeElement;
    this.loadMarker();
    this.loadCircle();
  }

  loadMarker() {
    this.marker?.load(`my animation`);
  }

  loadCircle() {
    this.circle?.load(`my animation`);
  }
}
```

```
<div class="marker-block">
  <lottie-player #markerRef autoplay mode="normal" class="marker-block__marker"></lottie-player>
  <lottie-player #circleRef mode="normal" class="marker-block__circle"></lottie-player>
</div>
```

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { RtMarkerComponent } from './rt-marker.component';

describe('RtMarkerComponent', () => {
  let component: RtMarkerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RtMarkerComponent>;

  beforeEach((() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RtMarkerComponent],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RtMarkerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

● RtMarkerComponent › should create

```
TypeError: this.marker?.load is not a function

  52 |
  53 |   loadMarker() {
> 54 |     this.marker?.load(`
```

It says this.marker?.load is not a function, **how to fix it?**

I tried to mock marker by creating object (with type HTMLLottiePlayerElement). But it shows another error message.
The code works well, but jest unit test fails.
If I use lottie animation then what should I add to unit tests?